# Reading issues in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

How do you view an issue in Xcode 4, so that you can read the whole issue?

Example (click to enlarge):
[image]

I could open the issue navigator and expand its width, however I would like to view the issue fast, so I can fix it fast (also click to enlarge):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Show the "Log navigator" (far right button on the panel on the left).
2. Click on the latest "Build

   Look on the right for a file which is showing a warning / error.

   Click the button on the far right of that line to open up the compiler input / output.

   Read the full message.